# how to highcharts livedata to drilldown

Tags: javascript

I want to live-data to live-data drilldown. What should I do?

live-data: https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/vs-load.csv

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 600
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Server Monitoring Demo'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Instance Load'
  },
  data: {
    csvURL: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/vs-load.csv',
    enablePolling: true,
    dataRefreshRate: 99991
  },


});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

fail drilldowns samples:

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {

          var chart = this,
            drilldowns = {
              'ec2-332-108-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com': {
                name: 'ec2-332-108-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                data: [
                  ['Cows', 2],
                  ['Sheep', 3]
                ]
              },
              'ec2-332-108-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com': {
                name: 'ec2-332-108-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                data: [
                  ['Apples', 5],
                  ['Oranges', 7],
                  ['Bananas', 2]
                ]
              },
              'ec2-332-108-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com': {
                name: 'ec2-332-108-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                data: [
                  ['Toyota', 1],
                  ['Volkswagen', 2],
                  ['Opel', 5]
                ]
              }
            },
            series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

          // Show the loading label
          chart.showLoading('Simulating Ajax ...');

          setTimeout(function() {
            chart.hideLoading();
            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
          }, 1000);
        }

      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Async drilldown'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    csvURL: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/vs-load.csv',
    enablePolling: true,
    dataRefreshRate: 99991,

    drilldown: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      colorByPoint: true,
      drilldown: true
    },
    series: {

      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.y:.0f}%',
        drilldown: true
      }
    }
  },


  drilldown: {
    series: []
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tk2bgno8/2/

Comment: update by late time keep not work http://jsfiddle.net/tk2bgno8/5/